# import package.* to import methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking at some examples of lwjgl 3. In their example code they import:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
```

I've seen this crop up many times now and I thought I'd just get round to asking. The code then goes on to lines such as:

```
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
```

Where it calls the function in the GLFW class. However, in my IDE (eclipse luna) this does not work as intended, I would need to call:

```
GLFW.glfwDestroyWindow(window);
```

Which isn't really a problem, just an inconvenience. How is it that I can get eclipse to recognise that this function is within the class imported so I do not have to direct it.

Comment: I'm using kepler, which is prior to luna and it works, not complaining about the missing static method. are you sure you're not just doing `import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*` instead of `import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*`? the [static is important](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Comment: The import is static, and the glfwDestroyWindow method is in the GLFW class and is callable by GLFW.glfwDestroyWindow, but not just glfwDestroyWindow -- I tested the same code in NetBeans and it causes the same problem. I am using Java 7 on Win7 x64

Comment: The code I'm testing is an exact copy of http://www.lwjgl.org/guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code in the [getting started](http://www.lwjgl.org/guide) is dependent on newer features of lwjgl 3, which means that if you download the (as of 2014-12-05) stable build from [the lwjgl download page](http://www.lwjgl.org/download), the code will not compile because classes referenced in the code are not present - the entire `org.lwjgl.glfw` package is missing from the stable download.

You must download one of the nightly builds in order to get the required functionality; this will most likely be resolved once the v3 of the library is fully released.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest nightly build (04 Dec 14 23:45), the glfw methods are present, however, unqualified referencing of its functions still throws up what eclipse thinks are errors.

Comment: Problem solved, the imports in the example were wrong, the class containing glfwDestroyWindow is not org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW but org.lwjgl.system.glfw.GLFW

Comment: You're still referencing the old lwjgl jar file if that's the case. If you compare the location of the `GLFW` class in the stable and nightly builds you'll see that they've changed quite significantly.